Flutter Firebase Remote Config not updating values on when fetch and activate
I am using Firebase Remote Config and load the values on every app start. The is working. But now I also want to be able to update and fetch it. I tried it by simply calling:
 await _remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate();

(same as I do when starting the app). But when calling it during the app is running, I don't get the updated values, when I update the config from Firebase.
What am I missing here?

Same for me. Have you solved?

@manudicri setting up a listener and then calling it inside the listener ended up working
